# Automated conversion of German text to IPA

Tags: phonetics, resource

[IPA = Internationales Phonetisches Alphabet]

Does anyone know of a tool like [**this one**](https://tophonetics.com/) that supports German?

For my purposes, the tool need not be free or web-based (though, if not web-based, it at least needs to run on Linux).  It's OK if it works only from the Unix shell (command-line), or if it requires programming (i.e. if it is in the form of a module/package/library for some programming language).

Comment: You are aware that, in German, writing does to some degree determine pronunciation, but that there are quite some ambiguities?

Comment: @tofro: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I'm not sure I understand why you point this out.

Comment: I think that obvious: Ambiguity leads to loss of reliability. Such a tool cannot be perfect.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want? Do you want the programme to transcribe written German texts into IPA? Or do you want the programme to transcribe spoken language using the IPA notation? (Both is actually impossible, but it would anyway be interesting what you intended.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: I gave an example of what I'm after in my original question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about the German language.

Comment: Please describe what _this one_ does in your question, that will make it easier to help you. (I don't want to familiarize myself with a tool so I can help you when you could just describe what you're looking for yourself.) Linguistics.SE might be a better fit for this question, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one:

http://tom.brondsted.dk/text2phoneme/transcribeit.php

No idea about reliability or usefulness.

Comment: This is interesting as an experiment, but I would use it with caution. - I did only one test: I entered the simple word "Brotkorb", and it renders: b r ɔ t k ɔ r p     - which is wrong. In standard German pronunciation the two "o" are distinctly different vowels, but the probramme stupidly puts ɔ everywhere. Also the first o needs to be long.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such a tool, but Wiktionary shows the pronunciation of every word as IPA-string. You find the pronunciation under the heading *»Aussprache«*.

Many words have different standard pronunciations in different regions, and some words also have two "global" standard pronunciations. Wiktionary lists some of them, but not all.

Example:
[»Kaffee« on Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaffee)

> Aussprache:
>   IPA: [ˈkafe], auch, österreichisch nur: [kaˈfeː]

There is also another online resource, that has its focus on standard pronunciations in different regions. This is [adaba.at](http://adaba.at). *»Adaba«* is an acronym for *»**A**ussprache**da**ten**ba**nk«* (pronunciation database). It shows the standard pronunciations for Germany, Austria and Switzerland.

Comment: I think that's the most reasonable answer one can give to that (problematic for various reasons) question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ipanow.com? It does Latin, Italian, German, and French.

Comment: Welcome to German SE. I haven’t tried ipanow myself, but they provide a short demonstration, and the IPA result looks a bit weird (at least for Latin and German).